# What is the best way to store a table in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm programming a decision tree in C++ using a slightly modified version of the [C4.5 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm). Each node represents an attribute or a column of your data set and it has a children per possible value of the attribute.

My problem is how to store the training data set having in mind that I have to use a subset for each node so I need a quick way to only select a subset of rows and columns.

The main goal is to do it in the most memory and time efficient possible (in that order of priority).

The best way I have thought of is to have an array of arrays (or std::vector), or something like that, and for each node have a list (array, vector, etc) or something with the `column,line`(probably a tuple) pairs that are valid for that node.

I now there should be a better way to do this, any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** What I need is something like this:

In the beginning I have this data:

```
Paris    4    5.0    True
New York 7    1.3    True
Tokio    2    9.1    False
Paris    9    6.8    True
Tokio    0    8.4    False
```

But for the second node I just need this data:

```
Paris    4    5.0
New York 7    1.3
Paris    9    6.8
```

And for the third node:

```
Tokio    2    9.1
Tokio    0    8.4
```

But with a table of millions of records with up to hundreds of columns.

What I have in mind is keep all the data in a matrix, and then for each node keep the info of the current columns and rows. Something like this:

```
Paris    4    5.0    True
New York 7    1.3    True
Tokio    2    9.1    False
Paris    9    6.8    True
Tokio    0    8.4    False
```

Node 2:

```
columns = [0,1,2]
rows = [0,1,3]
```

Node 3:

```
columns = [0,1,2]
rows = [2,4]
```

This way on the worst case scenario I just have to waste

```
size_of(int) * (number_of_columns + number_of_rows) * node
```

That is a lot less than having an independent data matrix for each node.

Comment: You might want to look at Loki's multimethods.
http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/main.html

Comment: Do you have a non-c++ implementation you would like to port (convert) to c++?  Otherwise, your question might get more attention on: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know if it serves your purposes, but seems to me that boost::multi_index is a thing for you to look for.

Comment: Not sure if this is solved or not nor wether this is what you wanted or not but ..
Why not make a struct and store the values in there then store each struct in an array/vector or list?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I tried to understand C4.5, I failed, but I have implemented a variant of ID3 - originally out of curiosity, but it eventually got used as part of an overkill multiple-dispatch code generator. This never deals with large data sets, though, and it's a good job. You wouldn't do well to imitate most of what I did, but maybe with a few exceptions, and of course I learned a bit from the mistakes.

I tend to think in terms of building a decision tree for an expert system, so I tend to use the following terms - sorry if that's confusing...

```
Column = Question ..... A question the expert system might ask
Row    = Conclusion ... A possible conclusion the expert system might reach
Cell   = Answer ....... For the question and conclusion, what answer should
                        the user be expected to give
```

Actually, in my case, I made the conclusion into another column - similar to a truth table for a logic gate. Row numbers were therefore just row numbers. This allowed me to handle XOR-style problems which can't even be represented if the same conclusion cannot appear on several rows. I'm not sure if this is relevant to you or not. In any case, I'm ignoring this below - it doesn't really make a lot of difference unless until you look at the details of choosing which question to ask next anyway. For data mining, you probably don't have a particular piece of information to treat as the target conclusion anyway - the "conclusion" is just whatever is left when you decide to stop asking questions.

So - for each decision tree node derived so far, you have a set of outstanding questions (columns) and a set of not-yet-eliminated conclusions (rows). That's what I did. The only point worth adding is I used bit-vectors.

IIRC, the C++ `std::vector<bool>` and `std::array<bool>` *may* be implemented as bit-vectors, but you're still reliant on the STL algorithms for set operations, which operate one item at a time. I used my own bit-vector class which has been gradually built up over a period of time, and which uses bitwise operators on the underlying `std::vector<CHUNK>` (where `CHUNK` is an unsigned int type, usually 32 bits wide).

There may be a better bit-vector option in C++11 or in Boost, and there must be some good libraries out there some where - there's plenty of kinds of program where you end up working with sets of unsigned integers. I just don't know much about them because I've been too lazy to switch from using my own.

However, bit-vectors are at there best when sets are mostly dense. In this case, the set of rows is the obvious problem. Only the root node of the decision tree will have a perfectly dense row-set. As you get further from the root, the row sets get sparser and sparser, with each question answered resulting in the set of rows been distributed between two or more disjoint next-node row sets.

So a simple sorted-array-of-row-numbers might be the best representation for these sets. However, it's also possible that a "sparse bit-vector" might be worthwhile. One possible implementation is a sorted array of pairs where the first of each pair is the first row-ID of a block and the second is a fixed-size bitvector for that block. For example, the row number 35 might be stored in block 32 (`35 & ~(32 - 1)`) in bit position 3 (`35 & (32 - 1)`). If you only save the pairs where the bitvector is non-zero, this gives something between a sorted array of IDs and a simple bitvector - it handles sparse arrays reasonably well, especially when IDs tend to cluster closely together in sets.

Also, it may be worthwhile using a class that can switch from a bitvector to a sorted-array representation when the size gets small enough. The extra complication, purely to benefit a few nodes near the root, is probably pointless though.

Anyway, however these sets are represented, as they refer back to a single constant "database", this saves a lot in data-copying and space-waste as the algorithm runs. But it's still worth looking at that "database".

I used an associative data structure, allowing me to look up using a tuple of question-ID and conclusion-ID to get a answer-ID. That means I had a per-item overhead for the key (question-ID and conclusion-ID) and in this case B+-style tree overhead as well. The reason - basically habit. I have containers that are very flexible, and I tend to use them a lot because it saves on anticipating what capabilities I'll actually need later. There's a price for that, but that's just the old premature optimisation thing.

In your case, you're using a matrix - I assume a two-dimensional array indexed by question-ID and answer-ID.

The only way I can imagine my version being more efficient that yours is if most answers aren't known. In a matrix, you need a special not-known answer ID for that, taking the same space as a known answer-ID. In an associative container, you exclude those rows.

Even so, a sorted array would be more efficient than my B+ tree based solution. You don't need to allow for efficient inserts, so the only necessary overhead is for the keys.

If you use two key fields (question and conclusion, row and column) that might be a problem (I don't really remember) - you maybe can't just keep one copy of the table in one sorted order. But if you use a single computed key along the lines of `(row * num_columns) + column`, you're basically implementing a two dimensional sparse array anyway.

For me, the presence of unknown/undefined answers for a particular question means I'm not allowed to ask that question yet - and even that was just the theory I used back when I first implemented the algorithm. I never actually put that to use. There's a use I could put it to, but I never got around to it. For the record, in that multiple-dispatch code generator, one idea was to dispatch based on fields in the type. As the type itself is polymorphic, those fields may not even be there, so it's only valid to look at them once you've confirmed that they must be present.

If you don't have an application for unknown/undefined answers, your existing matrix is probably the best solution already.

So basically, that's it - I can't really offer any clearly better options, and what you're doing is probably already better than what I did. However, there are some trade-off possibilities that you might consider - assuming that's not premature (and possibly false) optimisation, of course.

The main trade-off issue relates to the efficiency of representations of sparse vs. dense sets of values, so it isn't really specific to C4.5 or decision-tree building. And a more "sophisticated" approach is often less efficient than a simple one that was chosen with care.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is good. I am not sure how general your library for accessing the data you wish to be. But you could something like store your whole initial data in a `std::vector` of rows. If the columns are invariable for you, for the datatype I would choose [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#tuple_types) library.

Then, you could pass a handle to the whole "database" to your Node types. It would be very easy to retrieve/access any subset of columns and rows from such structure. A Node type would act as a kind of proxy object or wrapper to access the data, somewhat acting as a *view* for the whole database.

Moreover, the time cost would be constant in time, as the data would be accessed directly. The memory footprint would be 
low as you mentioned, cause the main cost is the initial database and there are no copies of the data itself made. Only cost would be indexes in from of the rows-columns vectors.

There is, however, one caveat. If you speak of millions of records and hundreds of columns, you need to remember there is a scalability limit for memory. You might be forced to resort to some real database system just be cause of memory amount limitations. I would advice probably SQLite. SQLite allows to create volatile in-memory database. So you can go with it initially and seamlessly transition into normal file DB if your data sets will grow too large.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do on your model to save some space is managing indexes on your nodes as bit arrays. So from your example:

> **Node 2:**
>
> columns = [0,1,2] = 5 or 101
>
> rows = [0,1,3] = 11 or  1011
>
> **Node 3:**
>
> columns = [0,1,2] = 5 or 101
>
> rows = [2,4] = 20 or 10100

This would take your requirement from size_of(int) * (number_of_columns + number_of_rows) * node
to sizeof(int) * 2 * node

This approach will restrict your matrix dimension to a sizeof(int) columns and same number of rows.
To overcome this limitation (specially strong on rows) you could store them on blocks. In that case, you
will need a new integer on each node specifying the block, making your total index size to sizeof(int)*3*node 
which is still lower than size_of(int) * (number_of_columns + number_of_rows) * node